# Why is the value of the prop not set in methods like componentWillUnmount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component `ServerTime` that renders timestamps emitted from a WebSocket connection.

```
<ServerTime webSocket={this.props.webSocket} />
```

In `componentDidMount` I register a callback using the EventEmitter API of the WebSocket.

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.webSocket.on('time', this.update);
}
```

This all works.

If I add a `componentWillUnmount` method to `ServerTime` and print out the value of `this.props.webSocket`, then the value of `webSocket` is its *initial* value (which is `false`).

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  console.log(this.props.webSocket); // false!
}
```

Why might the `webSocket` object not be available in `componentWillUnmount`?

What am I doing wrong here?

My hunch is that this is due to a misunderstanding on my part wrt reselect or immutable.js.

For info I am using redux, connect, reselect and immutable.js.

Comment: is `websSocket` a typo here or in your actual code? (in the console statement)

Comment: Thank you. The typo is in my question alone. fixed

Answer (score 0):

Immutable will create a new webSocket each time store's state is mutated, you can save the webSocket in component's state :

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  const {webSocket} = props;
  this.state = { webSocket };
}
```

and to access webSocket on unmount :

```
componentWillUnmount() {
  const {webSocket} = this.state;
  console.log(webSocket);
  // do something with webSocket
}
```

Comment: OK thank you. With your implementation, `this.props.webSocket` is `false` when retrieved in `componentWillUnmount`. So my problem still exists - why might this be?

Comment: @BenAston I updated the answer. It seems your websocket is a new instance every time it's passed as a prop.

Comment: Can you help me understand why immutable.js is "resetting" the value of websocket on the props? Can I stop it from doing so?

Comment: That's what immutable does. If there comes any change in the values or maps you use Immutable for, it will create a new copy each time mutation or a change tries to occur. Where do you keep webSocket, in your store or some component ?

Comment: I think this is because the way I am triggering the `componentWillUnmount` destroys the outer component first, hence the props value is reset before the `ServerTime` component is destroyed?

Comment: @BenAston will mount will be called before the component is destroyed. Have you tried my new answer yet ?

Comment: I have determined that my CONNECT (ie. attempt to establish WS connection) reducer is being run AFTER CONNECT_SUCCESS and this is resetting the value of webSocket in the store. I think. I don't know why the order of reducer execution is like this...